# Merging multiple maps

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-hana

I've already asked this on the boost mailinglist but I wasn't that clear about my intentions it seemed. It could also be me not completely understanding how I can accomplish this.

I want to merge multiple maps in hana, see the following code example:

```
constexpr auto m1 = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair("key1"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
    hana::make_pair("key2"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>)
);

constexpr auto m2 = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair("key3"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
    hana::make_pair("key4"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
    hana::make_pair("key5"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>)
);

constexpr auto m3 = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair("key6"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
    hana::make_pair("key7"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
    hana::make_pair("key8"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>)
);
```

I already got an answer how to do this for two maps:

```
constexpr auto result = hana::fold_left(m1, m2, hana::insert);
constexpr auto expected = hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair("key1"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
    hana::make_pair("key2"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
    hana::make_pair("key3"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
    hana::make_pair("key4"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>),
    hana::make_pair("key5"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>)
);
```

When I checked the documentation, I can see that fold_left takes 2 or 3 arguments.

It looks like I need something like:
fold_left(fold_left(m1, m3, hana::insert), m2, hana::insert);

```
template<typename Map...>
constexpr auto merge_multiple_maps(Map... args) {
  // do something useful here...
}
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here and I still haven't that much experience in meta programming...

Regards, Matthijs

Comment: How did you manage to compile your example? I keep getting `error: unable to find string literal operator ‘operator""_s’ with ‘const char [5]’, ‘long unsigned int’ arguments
     hana::make_pair("key1"_s, hana::type_c<std::string>)` on C++14 and GCC 7.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, define `merge2` as follows:

```
auto merge2 = [](auto&& m1, auto&& m2) {
  return hana::fold_left(std::forward<decltype(m1)>(m1),
                         std::forward<decltype(m2)>(m2),
                         hana::insert);
};
```

Then, define `merge` as the recursive application of `merge2`:

```
auto merge = [](auto&& m1, auto&& ...ms) {
  return hana::fold_left(
    hana::make_basic_tuple(std::forward<decltype(ms)>(ms)...),
    std::forward<decltype(m1)>(m1),
    merge2
  );
};
```

I did not test this implementation, but it should give you the idea. If you don't care about perfect forwarding, you can drop all the `static_cast`; this is just for runtime efficiency in case you are storing types that are expensive-to-copy-but-cheap-to-move in your map. Also, you won't be able to use this in a `constexpr` context because lambdas can't appear in constant expressions. This will be fixed in C++17, but for now you can implement function objects that are equivalent to these lambdas quite easily.

**[Edit: Hana may implement this `merge` function at some point in the future.]**
**[Edit: Use `std::forward` instead of `static_cast`.]**

Comment: Shouldn't `std::forward<decltype(m1)>(m1)` work, for self-documentation ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I have the habit of using `static_cast` in Hana's implementation because it causes 1 fewer function instantiation (and that makes a difference in Hana), but I'll edit my answer because `std::forward` is clearer.